# LiqPay — обращение к API

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить результат транзакции. Сформировал запрос по всем правилам. Вот [тут написано](https://liqpay.com/?do=pages&p=api): сформированный запрос необходимо послать по адресу: `https://www.liqpay.com/?do=api_xml`.

Только вот не объяснено, каким способом его туда послать. Хотелось бы узнать, как это можно сделать с помощью формы и метода `POST`.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае что-то типа:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://www.liqpay.com/?do=api_xml">
     <input type="hidden" name="operation_xml" value="<?=$operationXML?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?=$signature?>">
</form>
```

Как формировать поля `operation_xml` и `signature`, думаю, ужа сами разберетесь ( если уже не разобрались )

Comment: "С этим XML-файлом не связана ни одна таблица стилей." - вот что получается в итоге. Или не так формирую xml или уже не знаю что делать...

Comment: Вы должны отправлять base64_encode($xml) а не тупо XML.<br>
Начните с мат части :) И повнимательнее читайте доку...

Comment: <code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
 <liqpay>
  <operation_envelope>      
   <operation_xml>
    '.$xml_encoded.'
  </operation_xml>
  <signature>
   '.$sign.'
  </signature>
 </operation_envelope>
 </liqpay>
</request>
</code>

Отправлял в таком виде вместе с зашифрованной сигнатурой. Одна и та же картина. Ну не шифровать же этот xml ещё раз (

Comment: уважаемый аффтар - читайте жокументаци. внимательно пожалуйста, весь XML у вас должен хранится в 1ой переменной и вы должны отправлять base64_encode вашего XML'я а не то что вы отправляете...

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример из документации:

```
<?php
    $key = '143fd234323fdsf';
    $request =
        '<request>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <action>send_money</action>
            <kind>phone</kind>
            <merchant_id>i1234567890</merchant_id>
            <order_id>ORDER_123</order_id>
            <to>+3801234567890</to>
            <amount>10</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <description>Here is your 10 buck</description>
            </request>';
    $post =
        '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
        <request>
            <liqpay>
                <operation_envelope>
                    <operation_xml>' .
                        base64_encode($request) .
                    '</operation_xml>
                    <signature>' .
                        base64_encode(sha1(
                            $key .
                            $request .
                            $key,
                            1
                        )) .
                    '</signature>
                </operation_envelope>
            </liqpay>
        </request>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.liqpay.com/?do=api_xml');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "POST /?do=api_xml HTTP/1.0",
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($post)
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo $result;
```

Что в нем Не понятно ?
Отправляем методом POST, формирование xml достаточно банально.

Comment: А если без curl?

Comment: для тех кто в танке, цитата доки - <b>Далее XML упаковывается с помощью функции base64_encode(PHP) или encode_base64(Perl).</b><br>
И отправляется именно форма, Content-type: text/xml? нуну...<br>
а не application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: В документации у них очень мутно на эту тему, так что приходится смотреть на пример использования, а там что-то типа XML-RPC. Следовательно `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` здесь ни разу не уместен

Comment: Ну я не уверен на 100%, но, например, что касается покупки товаров то отправляется именно форма - это факт. Судя по тому что здесь мы отправляем абсолютно теже данный `operation_xml` & `signature`, все это отправляется <b>формой</b>. Соответственно заголовок content-type должен быть именно application/x-www-form-urlencoded<br>
Вы логически подумайте - зачем тогда делать `base64_encode`, если бы было бы text/xml - то вы бы не смогли отправить signature вне XML'я + зачем вообще тогда base64_encode, подумайте над этим... И у вас не отправляется signature вообще( отдельно )

Comment: хотя насчет мутно согласен на 100%

Comment: Если отправлять формой - то нет смысла городить весь этот xml с `<request><liqpay><operation_envelope>` - просто отправляй две переменные operation_xml=base64_запроса&signature=base64_подписи, а тут они чего-то мутят с xml и в документации что-то про несколько запросов передать. C формой получилось-бы не слишком надежно

Comment: Какая разница передавать формой или еще как-то?<br>
По-моему важно "что" передавать, что "не слишком надежного" непонятно...<br>
В том смысле что дюпнут signature? Вероятность этого примерно такая-же как то что сейчас наступит апокалипсис (утрирую)

Comment: Касаемо не слишком надежно, в случае передачи через xml запрос и подпись будут идти в одном `<operation_envelope>`, а в случе передачи через `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` порядок запросов и подписей к ним ни кто не гарантирует